# Creating Variables foreach Info a cmdlet delivers

Tags: windows, powershell, automation

So a bit of a Rookie Question here i guess, but Google can't help me anymore, since I'm lacking the terms to describe what I want to do.

What I want to do is simply ask for the State of .NET Framework Optional WindowsFeatures and - if one of them is not installed, do so.

My approach was to

```
Get-WindowsOptionalFeature -Online | Where-Object {$_.FeatureName -clike "Net*"}
```

Output is Expected to be:

```
FeatureName : NetFx3
State       : DisabledWithPayloadRemoved

FeatureName : NetFx4-AdvSrvs
State       : Disabled

FeatureName : NetFx4Extended-ASPNET45
State       : Disabled
```

Now I want to Parse this to a Foreach Method so every Feature, where State=Disabled* gets installed.

I tried to create a Variable foreach of those where the Name of the Variable is also what was given as an Value, such as:

```
$NetFx3 = Netfx3
```

And this - as I said - for each of the Features that are currently Disabled but not for any other.

This way I could just use them, but there should be an easier way, which I cannot see...

Comment: You can change your condition to `Where-Object {$_.FeatureName -like "Net*" -and $_.State -ne 'Enabled'}` to only get feature that are not enabled. If you pipe this to `Enable-WindowsOptionalFeature` you're done.

Answer (score 0):

If you pipe the output of your current command into `ForEach-Object`, PowerShell will **automatically create a variable for you.**

Try it and you will find you'll have an object called `$psItem` which contains all of the properties for an item of the list, and it automatically moves on to the next item in the list too.

```
Get-WindowsOptionalFeature -Online | Where-Object {$_.FeatureName -clike "Net*"}| 
  ForEach-Object{
    Write-host "The status of the feature called $($PSItem.FeatureName) is $($PSItem.State)"
   }
```

#### Sidebar, fun with variables

Since I get the impression you might be interested in knowing a few fun tricks, I encourage you to play with the output and see what the properties are, which is sooo easy!

Just slap `-OutVariable myVar` to the end like this.  Here's some fun commands to get you started.

```
Get-WindowsOptionalFeature -Online | Where-Object {$_.FeatureName -clike "Net*"} -OutVariable myVar

#pick the first item in the list and see some properties
>$myVar[0]

FeatureName : NetFx3
State       : Enabled

#see ALL of its properties

>$myVar[0] | Format-List * -Force
FeatureName      : NetFx3
State            : Enabled
Path             :
Online           : True
WinPath          :
SysDrivePath     :
RestartNeeded    : False
LogPath          : C:\WINDOWS\Logs\DISM\dism.log
ScratchDirectory :
LogLevel         : WarningsInfo


#access one or two of them
>$myvar[0] | select FeatureName, Online,LogPath

FeatureName Online LogPath
----------- ------ -------
NetFx3        True C:\WINDOWS\Logs\DISM\dism.log

#get those same properties for every item in the list
> $myvar | select FeatureName, Online,LogPath

FeatureName             Online LogPath
-----------             ------ -------
NetFx3                    True C:\WINDOWS\Logs\DISM\dism.log
NetFx4-AdvSrvs            True C:\WINDOWS\Logs\DISM\dism.log
NetFx4Extended-ASPNET45   True C:\WINDOWS\Logs\DISM\dism.log

#Save a spreadsheet with this info
> $myvar | select FeatureName, Online,LogPath | Export-Csv C:\pathTo\This.csfv -NoTypeInfo
```

### Back to your question

However, if you wanted to automatically install any roles that were missing you could do this.

```
$missingDotNet =  Get-WindowsOptionalFeature -Online | Where-Object {$_.FeatureName -clike "Net*" -and $_.State -ne 'Enabled'}
if ($missingDotNet.Count -eq 0){
   Write-Host "All Dotnet features installed (or not running as Admin)"
}
else{
   Enable-WindowsOptionalFeature $missingDotNet
}
```

Comment: Hey there, thanks for the great help!
Also thank you for your additional information on "Fun with Variables" :D

Answer (score 0):

At the end, I went into an Error, because what the Variable was giving out seemed to be "$_.FeatureName = NetFx3"

But with the code following I was able to get it running.

```
    #####Check on all .Net Features
    $missingDotNet =  Get-WindowsOptionalFeature -Online | Where-Object {$_.FeatureName -clike "Net*" -and $_.State -ne 'Enabled'} | Select -ExpandProperty FeatureName

#####If no .Net Feature is missing Script just prints "All .NET Features are installed or not running as Admin (no guarantee)"
    if ($missingDotNet.Count -eq 0){
       Write-Host "All .NET Features installed or not running as Admin"
    }
#####If there are .Net Features that are missing this line will install them
    else
    {
        Enable-WindowsOptionalFeature -Online -FeatureName ($missingDotNet)
    }
```

So now - since the Script is meant to install SAP GUI install completley - I can crawl back into my cave and get the rest done.